# cilent side password encryption in jQuery ajax + PHP [advance]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, password-encryption

I got the answer [here](https://coders4u.wordpress.com/2018/02/06/encrypt-password-on-client-side-and-decrypt-on-server-side-using-jquery-and-php/) how to encrypt post data in javascript and same decrypt it on server side. I am facing an issue while implementing the javascriot with my ajax form submission. I try to implement it with my ajax as below in my code snippet bit it not works as expected.

I don't have advance use of jQuery with this function but I can learn with someone provide the correct solution of this thread.
I show multiple threads on this same platform stackoverflow but the question bit similar but my answer is totally end-to-end diffrent. Please don't mark it as spam/duplicate/pending. Thank you stackover devs,

```js
$("#form").unbind("submit").bind("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function encrypt() {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef");
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("abcdef9876543210abcdef9876543210");

    var newpassword = $('input[name="newpassword"]');

    var hash = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(newpassword, key, {
      iv: iv
    });
    $('input[name="newpassword"]').val() = hash;

    //alert(hash);
    return false;
  }


  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute("RECAPTCHA_SECRET_CODE", {
      action: "updatepass"
    }).then(function(token) {
      let formData = {
        token: token,
        newpassword: newpassword
      };
      timeExecute = new Date().getTime();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.status == "success") {
            $(form)[0].reset();
            alert("Password Changed");
          } else {
            alert("ERROR");
          }
        },
        timeout: 10000,
        async: false
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="//crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=RECAPTCHA_SECRET_CODE"></script>
<form class="cust-form" id="form" method="POST">
  <div class="password-input">
    <input type="password" id="reg_pass" class="form-control" autofocus="true" name="newpassword" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="passwordBtn">Change Password</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I suggest using HTTPS

Comment: What isn't working the way you'd like to? If something doesn't work, many a time it's because there stands to be errors somewhere. Are you checking for them? Did you enable error reporting for the PHP and looked at your developer console? If this is database related, are you also checking for errors? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It not showing the encrypted password and not post ant data as well..

Comment: This: `$('input[name="newpassword"]').val() = hash;` should be `$('input[name="newpassword"]').val(hash);`

Comment: And this: `var newpassword = $('input[name="newpassword"]');` should be `var newpassword = $('input[name="newpassword"]').val();` The `.val()` returns the value of the selected elements and `.val(value)` sets the value of selected elements. You are preventing form submission with `e.preventDefault()`. So you should trigger form submission manually after inserting the hashed password.

Comment: @user3647971 It tough to get what you actually want to say.. could you please reply me with exactly in code snippet? please so I can understand properly. Thank you

Comment: @Shubham I answered with the corresponding code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#form").unbind("submit").bind("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      encrypt();//call the function you declared
      function encrypt() {
          var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef");
          var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("abcdef9876543210abcdef9876543210");

          var newpassword = $('input[name="newpassword"]').val();//get the value

          var hash = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(newpassword, key, {
            iv: iv
          });
          $('input[name="newpassword"]').val(hash);//insert the hashed value
          
          //alert(hash);
          return false;
      }
      $('#form').submit();//submit the form manually if you use e.preventDefault()
});
```

And in your `button` element:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="passwordBtn">Change password</button>
```